# Adding IBActions to UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, ibaction

Hey, I was wondering if it would be possible to add IBActions to a UIScrollView? So when the user has scrolled to the next image an IBAction is done?

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to implement the [UIScrollViewDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate) and implement the `-scrollViewDidScroll:` method. In that method, you could use `UIScrollView`'s `contentOffset` property to determine the current scroll position, and from there figure out what image it has scrolled to.

Comment: Ok, Is there any scroll project you would recommend me to use? I think I know how to make it do an action now but I don't know how to set up a working scroll view for images that will stop at each image. So I thought you maybe know about a project or a tutorial I could base this from?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is UIScrollView's paging feature. Check out this example project: https://github.com/ykyuen/ScrollViewWithPaging

Comment: Hmm, you don't think you maybe could customize the project to work with images instead and upload to mediafire or something when you got time, so I can try to add the actions? I'm sorry for asking but I'm not getting it work :(

Comment: Do you think you could do that when you got time? :)

Comment: I tried creating it out of the label code but I can't get it working.